how would I calculate the greenhouse effect based on the atmospheric composition
So say I have a planet that has an atmosphere of 1 atm, and is 78% N2, 20.16% CO2 0.84% O2 and 1% Ar, and it orbits a star that is about 40% as bright as the sun, the planet orbits at a distance of 0.82 Au, has an albedo of 0.29 and without any greenhouse effect the surface temperature is about -56 c or 217K
how would I determine the greenhouse effect based on the composition of the atmosphere? and can you make it as simple and easy to understand, because I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed
Edit: the temperature was wrong

it never hurts to check out our List of Worldbuilding Resources.
